# Hide word doc or pdf in image/ video using python

Tags: python-3.x, steganography

How to hide a word document or a pdf file in an image or video and preserve it's formatting on decoding using python?

Comment: A(ny) file is just a series of 1s and 0s, so in the same way you'd hide some text in a image, you can also hide anything else.

Comment: But how to extract back the fidden file in original format and formatting?

Comment: You extract the bits like you would and you write it all that as a binary file. Then it's all taken care for you. Some programs will figure out what kind of file it is based on its header. But if you want, you can also hide the filename/extension along with the file bytestream and get that back as well.

Comment: 'Some programs' like what? Please elaborate. Would be a great help.